# Why can I return a local variable for int& f1 in this instance

Tags: c++, reference, local

I need to determine whether the syntax of:

`int& f1(int i, int& j) { int& k = i; j+=i; return k; }`

is correct.

I have tested it, and to my astonishment, it compiles.

My understanding, since our function `f1` is of of type `int&` it cannot return local variables. By calling the function, I create a local variable `i`. When I set `int& k = i`, I am setting the memory space of `k` to that of `i`. Therefore `k` is a local variable and thus it should not compile, since local variable `k`is returned.

Any explanations are extremely helpful.

Comment: I get, as expected, a warning on your code: `warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary: i` (msvc 15). Even if it's compiles without errors, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: "...it cannot return local variables." you can do all sorts of strange things in c++, but just because you can doesnt make them correct

Comment: also, note that returning a reference to a local variable is not a syntax error. The syntax of this code is fine